# how to remove struct name from printed struct (swift4)

Tags: ios, swift, struct, printing

My code below prints a structs data. I just want to print struct data without the name of the struct. How can I do this? Also see pic below.

```
   var contacts = [Person]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
    @IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
        contacts.append(Person(name: a.text!,  phone: Int(c.text!)!))
        print(self.contacts.description)

        label.text = self.contacts.description
    }

    struct Person {
        var name: String

        var phone: Int

    }}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting multiple questions of the same issue. You should read more carefully and pay more attention at the answers already provided at your previous questions.

Comment: BTW you still using integers for phone numbers no matter how many times people warns you about it. Change it to String!!! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a protocol named **CustomStringConvertible** which should be used for printing Struct. Below I have demonstrated a simple code provided by apple in their documentation.

```
    struct Point {
         let x: Int, y: Int
    }

    let p = Point(x: 21, y: 30)
    print(p)
    // Prints "Point(x: 21, y: 30)"
```

Documentation says: *After implementing the description property and declaring CustomStringConvertible conformance, the Point type provides its own custom representation*

```
     extension Point: CustomStringConvertible {
        var description: String {
        return "(\(x), \(y))"
        }
     }

     print(p)
     // Prints "(21, 30)"
```

[Link is here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

Comment: Are both these sections of code stand alone meaning they don't relate to each other. Or do they need each other to work?

Comment: they need each other to work. please check out the link I have provided right under the last segment of my code

Comment: You should check [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614785/print-appended-struct-swift4?noredirect=1&lq=1). See the last answer given by rmaddy